# Running tests in different browsers

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit4

I have 3 tests defined in 3 different classes

Class 1
@Test 1

Class 2
@Test 2

Class 3
@Test 3

I have created another class 'Class Browsers' in which I am creating different browser drivers

Now I want to call @Test1,2 & 3 from the browsers class so that these tests are executed in different browsers

Is the following  right approach?

```
Class Browsers
{

public static Class1 A =new Class1()
public static Class2 B =new Class2()
public static Class3 C =new Class3()

@Test
public void createCromeDriver(){

A.Test1
B.Test2
C.Test3
}

@Test
public void createIEDriver(){
A.Test1
B.Test2
C.Test3
}

}
```

(In the above scenario I am calling tests which belongs to other classes into another class having its own tests.)

Comment: Does that approach work for you?

Answer (score 0):

While that does run all of the tests, it assumes you only want to know about one test failure per driver.  If all three IE tests fail, do you want three failures so you know this all at once?  I would.

To deal with that, you use a [Parameterized JUnit Test](https://blogs.oracle.com/jacobc/entry/parameterized_unit_tests_with_junit).  This lets you write code like this.  JUnit will call each of the tests with each of the parameters.  In my example, it runs the two tests with the IE browser.  You can add as many drivers as you want to the browsers() method to have it call the two tests with each of those browsers.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Browsers {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public Browsers(WebDriver _driver) {
        driver = _driver;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<WebDriver[]> browsers() {
        List<WebDriver[]> list = new ArrayList<WebDriver[]>();
        list.add(new WebDriver[] { new InternetExplorerDriver() });
        return list;
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
       A.test1(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
      B.test2(driver);
    }

}
```